# facebook app is not displaying in the facebook frame using .net

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps

I am not able to display my app on fb frame.I don't know whether it will work out or not.

i given like this. "http://127.0.0.1/fbinfo/"

for page tab also i given like this.

The problem is the out put is

How can we debug the facebook app in our local system.I am using C#.Net and ASP.Net technologies.

My requirement is like this if a fb user loggedin and come to our app and if he clicks then we will display a code otherwise we will collect his info and store it into our site and display a code.I want to develop in asp.net and c#.net

Answer (score 0):

Is your application installed on the Fan Tab? And has your app been correctly setup to point to your local environment?